# Angular 8 Lighthouse : Requests the notification permission on page load

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, lighthouse

how to do a conditioning and how to add code in this code for the user so that the lighthouse does not display the message. I tried some conditioning but the results are still the same, is there anyone here who can help me ?

Note : if the notification pop-up is rejected (block), "permission denied" does not appear and still shows "permission success". Thanks :)

this my code in home.component

```html
requestPermission() {
    this.msgService.requestToken.subscribe(
      (tokenize) => {
        console.log('Permission Success',tokenize);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log("Denied", error);
      }
    )
}
```

[error in null but "permission success" stay tuned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb2nt.png)

Lighthouse :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0agY.png)

Comment: why you are getting jquery error?

Comment: Lighthouse is basically telling you **not** to request the permission on the page load. Are you asking us how to trick lighthouse?

Comment: 1. jquery is a problem with adminlte.js and has nothing to do with it

Comment: I don't recommend tricking the lighthouse but how to connect requestToken and requestPermission so that the error doesn't appear like in the picture @JSONDerulo

Comment: It's unclear for me what you are trying to achieve and what your problem is. Also the code you provided is not very helpful.

Comment: so i made a push notification for angular and i imitated this from youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rDd4_-dMFo
but most people use SWPush and requestPermission to avoid getting permission errors in the lighthouse. The tutorial uses requestToken so my program gets permission errors in the lighthouse. that's the short story my friend @JSONDerulo